# How to prevent value from changing automatically in java

Tags: java

I'm very new to Java and stackoverflow so I'm sorry if I seem ignorant but I wrote this program to multiply two numbers together using the Russian Peasant multiplication algorithm. The complete program includes far more operations and is hundreds of lines of code but I only included what I thought was necessary for this particular method. I have a test harness so I know that all the submethods work correctly.  The problem that I'm struggling with though is the 3rd line where I'm adding factor1 to the product. The values add correctly but then when factor1 is multiplied by 2 in the 5th line then the value that was added to product in the 3rd line also gets doubled resulting in an incorrect product value. How can I make sure that when factor 1 is doubled that it doesn't carry backwards to the product term?

```
while (Long.parseLong(factor2.toString()) >= 1) {
    if (factor2.bigIntArray[0] % 2 == 1) {
        product = product.add(factor1);
    }
        factor1 = factor1.multiplyByTwo();
        factor2 = factor2.divideByTwo();

}
```

Comment: *How can I make sure that when factor 1 is doubled that it doesn't carry backwards to the product term?* - Use a different local variable when assigning result of `factor1.multiplyByTwo();`

Comment: What are the data types of `factor2`, `factor`, and `product`?

Answer (score 0):

I think in your method multiplyByTwo you use code

```
`datamember=datamember*2;`
```

rather than that try doing this
    `return new FactorClass(datamember*2);`
   so it doesnt change the added value.
   it would be better if u could show the mulTiplyByTwo method code since that is where your actually are getting the changed value.